# Is there a way to order Rows in a particular order based on when they were entered?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, rows

So I am building a Master Sheet for job tracking in Google Sheets. This master sheet uses a query IMPORTRANGE formula that pulls from 5 sheets in total.

Each of the 5 sheets will belong to someone different. Each of the 5 sheets has data entry that goes across a row. As an employee enters customer info, that info is pulled onto the Master Sheet. What I want is for the rows that get pulled from these 5 sheets to the master sheet, to stay in order as they come in.

For example if "Joe" enters customer info on his sheet, that info gets pulled to the master sheet as he enters it. If "Sam" enters customer info on his own sheet, say 5 minutes after Joe did, I don't want Sams row to push Joes row down, I just want each row added to be added below the one that is already there on the master sheet.

This is my formula and A2 is a date. I don't want the dates ordered be asc or desc I just want them added as someone enters this info on their sheet. Sort of a "first come first served" type of thing. Like Joe enters his customer info and that is added to the first row on the master sheet. When Sam enters his info I want his info to be the second line.

```
=QUERY({
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YXphsJ-qHwvkPXZ-K4T73wjoYrAMO3tDLHHtnJ3rCR4/edit#gid=1010940401","INSERT CUSTOMER INFO!A2:O");
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t1k_D6KEBgEDu2JcsOCy2LcJKhDaFobYjD8CpS0I-KA/edit#gid=1621769518","INSERT CUSTOMER INFO!A2:O");
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TRi-vqXl20s3wbO8JkJFhU7BSzzbJuPR1RyL-H3ZrRg/edit#gid=1621769518","INSERT CUSTOMER INFO!A2:O");
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MicctQHhtkB6HVkaCmKdh-F4R8jtCRSCRenLrfRsz_E/edit#gid=1621769518","INSERT CUSTOMER INFO!A2:O")
},"where Col1 is not null")
```

Answer (score 1):

not possible unless you use a **[timestamping script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets%2Btimestamp?tab=Newest)** which will record the exact datetime of each entry on second intervals upon every edit of given cell/range

without script, you will need to decide the priority of every slave sheet

Comment: Thank you! I didn't use a script but that sent me on a search and ending up finding how to add a timestamp using a IFS statement, so when data was entered in a cell it timestamped the cell before it. (Had to use iterative calculations) but that did the trick when it was added to the master sheet. It keeps them in order based on that timestamp.